# GPars paralell write, when are all files written?

Tags: groovy, gradle, gpars

So if I have a block that looks like:

```
def fileTree = project.fileTree("someDir/")
GPars.withPool(threads,exceptionHandler) {
  fileTree.eachParallel { File -> 
   //Load the file, transform the data and write it to a new file name. 
  } //End of eachParallel
}//End of withPool
```

At what point are all the files written, flushed and ready to be used in additional code?  At the `End of eachParallel` or at the `End of withpool`? ...or is special code needed to manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it depends on your `eachParallel` implementation, but it should be done in there.

Comment: That would be the default implementation.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I mean you have to take care of writing/flushing the file within the eachParallel block